# countdown timer implementation in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am Implementing a countdown timer in my app. In the functionality, I need to display the remaining time before Jan 1st 2011. In months, days, hours and minutes format.
Can any one please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an `NSTimer` which update you're label everytime it's fired

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html